# Prove by induction that $1+2^n<3^n$ for $n \ge 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction

I tried solving the following problem but I'm  little unsure of whether the prove is valid or not.

> Problem: Prove by induction that $1+2^n<3^n$ for $n \ge 2$

Base: $$1+2^2<3^2 \implies 5<9$$

Suppose that $1+2^n<3^n$ is true for all $n \ge 2$

Induction step:
    $$1+2^{n+1} < 3^{n+1}$$
Left side: 
$$1+2^{n+1} = 1+2^n2 = 3^n2$$
Right side:
$$3^{n+1} = 3^n3$$
So since $$3^n2 < 3^n3$$ it holds.

EDIT (changes to original post, so that proof is right.):

Suppose that $1+2^n<3^n$ is true for ***some*** $n \ge 2$

For left side use induction hypothesis that $1+2^n<3^n$. So
$$1+2^{n+1} = 1+2^n2 < 3^n2$$

Comment: On the induction step, why did you write $1+2^n 2=3^n 2$? The induction hypothesis means, that $1+2^n <3^n$, therefore $1+2^n 2 < 3^n 2 < 3^n 3=3^{n+1}$

Comment: After "Left side" you should say
$$1 + 2^{n+1} = 1 + 2^n2 < 2 + 2^n2 < 3^n2$$
to use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Induction hypothesis is "Suppose that $1+2^n<3^n$ is true **for some** $n\geq 2$", not "for **all**."  For the induction step, you want to start with $1+2^{n+1}$ and *not* immediately write the right hand side you want.  In a single line and a chain of equalities and inequalities, arrive at the intended right hand side at the very end of that chain.  $1+2^{n+1}\leq \dots \leq \dots < \dots \leq 3^{n+1}$ where there is at least one strict inequality in the chain.

Comment: Incidently, there's a simple direct way to prove this since for $n > 1$:

$$1^n + 2^n = {n\choose 0}1^n + {n\choose n}2^n < \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}1^{n-k}2^{k} = (1 + 2)^n = 3^n$$

this does not answer OP's question though.

Comment: @DarthGeek why do you have that 1+2^n*2<2+2^n*2, rather than just 1+2^n*2<3^n*2 ?

Comment: We know that $1+2^n < 3^n $, so if we multiply both sides by $2$ we get $2+2^n2 < 3^n2$. And naturally  $1+2^n2 < 2+2^n2$. The first inequality involves *what we know* and the second one connects it to *what we have*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof by Induction that $3^n ≥ 1+2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966128/proof-by-induction-that-3n-%e2%89%a5-12n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems in you proof is that you don't make use of the inductive hypothesis, at least not explicitly. The other problem is in the line:

$$1 + 2\cdot 2^n = 2\cdot 3^n$$

This isn't true. In fact if you can use the inductive hypothesis to prove that $1 + 2\cdot2^n \le 2\cdot 3^n$ and this will lead you to solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for quick respons. So is it correctly understood the edit i made to the original post in terms of using the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @sn3jd3r $1 + 2^{n+1} < 2 + 2^{n+1} = 2(1 + 2^n) < 2\cdot 3^n = 3^{n+1}$ is better, as it isn't so trivial to get you relation.

Comment: Might be a stupid question but would love to know the reason that it is necessary to write 1+2^n*2<2+2^n*2, rather than just (1+2^n)*2<2*3^n

Comment: @sn3jd3r Usually in inductive proof you want to use the inductive hypothesis explicitly. After all it's not clear from where did you obtain that inequality.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say $1+2^n2=3^n2$. It is wrong.

For your induction you should start on the RHS and try to achieve the LHS.
$$
3^{n+1}=3\cdot 3^n > \ldots >1+2^{n+1}
$$
You can use $3^n>1+2^n$ and $3>1$ and $3>2$. If you to it in the right order, you get it.

Comment: Thanks for quick respons. So is it correctly understood the edit i made to the original post in terms of using the induction hypothesis