# Inductive proof of: $3^n ≥ 1 + 2^n $, every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: proof-verification, induction

How can I prove by induction that $3^n ≥ 1 + 2^n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: By the way, for all n>0

Comment: Do you know how to factor $x^n - y^n$?

Comment: $(x-y)(x^n-1 + x^n-2 y + ... + x y^n-2 + y^n-1)$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Can you please add your thoughts and attempts at solving this problem?  Otherwise, I'm afraid your post will be closed very quickly .... Please see [How to ask a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Actually ı dont know how to prove $x^n-y^n$ but ı know the equality above

Comment: @ACrescendo: not exactly. The second factor is $\;x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dots +xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1}$ (the sum of all monomials in $x$ and $y$ of total degree $n-1$).

Comment: In the title, you say $n\in\Bbb N$ whereas in the comments, you state $n\gt 0$. Are you allowing all positive reals $n$ or not?

Comment: Actually ,n∈ℕ and n>0 together

Comment: Yes,Bernard ı think ı did misspelling

Comment: And another one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2459345/prove-by-induction-that-12n3n-for-n-ge-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have to prove that $$3^{n+1}\geq 2^{n+1}+1$$ if we multiply $$3^n\geq 2^n+1$$ by $3$ we obtain
$$3^{n+1}\geq 2^n\cdot 3+3$$ and we must show that $$2^n\cdot 3+3\geq 2^{n+1}+1$$
and this is true since
$$2^n\cdot 3+3=2^{n+1}+2^n+3\geq 2^{n+1}+1$$ which is true,.

Comment: what is wrong with my proof? thanks for the $-1$!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: (+1) I see one of  the same downvote maniacs struck again!

Comment: no, this proof is wrong

Comment: what is wrong? tell me please? you can not say it is without tell me why?

Comment: Ok ,firstly u say true about 3^(n+1)≥2^(n+1)+1 but that is  the fact we dont know yet, you cannot use it in your proof.

Comment: ok $$2^n\cdot 3+3=2^n(2+1)+3=2^{n+1}+2^n+3\geq 2^{n+1}+1$$!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I always thought that the 1st thing 1st is checking against the duplicates and I found at least 2

Comment: i only use the $$3^n\geq 2^n+1$$

Comment: i have written we have to prove, that....

Comment: Yes Dr Sonnhard , thank you it is a good proof,ı went through again and after your comment it became clearer

Comment: ok, this is good, we all want to do good mathematics

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1$ you just get $3\geq 2+1$, which is clearly true.
Assume now that the thesis holds for a fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e. assume that $3^n\geq 1+2^n$. We shall prove that it holds for $n+1$, too, i.e.
$$ 
3^{n+1}\geq 1+2^{n+1},
$$
which can be written as
$$
3\cdot 3^n\geq 1+2\cdot2^{n}.
$$
Now, notice that $3\cdot 3^n=(1+2)\cdot 3^n=3^n+2\cdot 3^n$, so we want to show that:
$$
3^n+2\cdot 3^n\geq 1+2\cdot2^{n}.
$$
We know by induction that 
$$
2\cdot 3^n\geq 2+2\cdot 2^n.
$$
It is quite clear that $2+2\cdot 2^n\geq 1+2\cdot 2^n$ and that $3^n\geq 0$ if $n\in\mathbb{N}$: this means that $3^n+2\cdot 3^n\geq 2\cdot 3^n$. Now, we have the chain of (in)equalities:
$$
3^{n+1}=3^n+2\cdot 3^n\geq 2\cdot 3^n\geq 1+2\cdot 2^n=1+2^{n+1},
$$
which gives the thesis.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need induction for this: $\;3^n\ge 1+2^n\iff 3^n-2^n\ge 1$. Now
$$3^n-2^n=\underbrace{(3-2)}_{=\,1}(\underbrace{3^{n-1}+3^{n-2}\cdot 2+\dots +2\cdot3^{n-2}+2^{n-1}}_{\text{each term in this sum is }\ge 1}).$$

Comment: thanks, it is a good perspective,too